# Can we call dance exercises "movements"?

Tags: word-usage

I don't know if there is any specific word to describe basic exercises in dance lessons.

For example in the fitness gym I can say I do 2 exercises for my arms: first curl barbell, second curl dumbbells.

But I don't know if it's normal to use the word "exercise" also for different dance movements?

EDIT: By movements I mean these two examples:  [First](https://www.google.com/search?q=salsa%20basic%20steps&oq=salsa%20basic&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57j0i512l8.7537j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_YxBTYvBrlNKQ8g-jnr_wDg18) & [Second](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhrdh-uFkog)  . I don't know how to call them when I want to refer one of them and talk about it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "basics".  Perhaps if you explained what sort of movements you did.   Also, what kind of dance class?  Ballet? Tango?

Comment: @JamesK: For example this is one of those movements: https://www.google.com/search?q=salsa+basic+steps&oq=salsa+basic&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57j0i512l8.7537j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_YxBTYvBrlNKQ8g-jnr_wDg18     Also this is the other one:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhrdh-uFkog

Answer (score 2):

For dancing, the basics that you practice are commonly called "movements".

It's in this sense from Merriam-Webster's:

> **movement**
> **1 a (2) :** a particular instance or manner of moving
> // *was entranced by her graceful movements*

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/pli%C3%A9) uses the term "movement" to describe the ballet movement called "plié":

> **plié**
> A dance **movement** in which the knees are bent

There's also the term "step", here defined in [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/step):

> **step**
> **2 a (2) :** a combination of foot or foot and body movements constituting a unit or a repeated pattern
> // *a dance step*

The term "step" is more often used for official standard movements in a particular dance style (like "plié", above), where "movement" can describe just about anything you do in dance.